# How are monitors and condition variables related?

Tags: semaphore, monitor, condition-variable

```
wait(mutex);
...
body of F
...
if (next count > 0)
signal(next);
else
signal(mutex);
```

This is the code for the monitor, but I don't understand how it's supposed to be related to the condition variables x.

```
x count++;
if (next count > 0)
signal(next);
else
signal(mutex);
wait(x sem);
x count--;
```

Here we have the code for wait()

```
if (x count > 0) {
next count++;
signal(x sem);
wait(next);
next count--;
}
```

Here we have the code for signal()

I know that wait() and signal() are used to send out 1 process at a time to the monitor so it can queue them to insure atomic access to shared data, but I don't understand how the code is supposed to work, because signal mutex in wait() is kind of useless here (mutex in the monitor being initialized to 1 already). Is the monitor running on a different thread and are the condition variables and the monitor using the same semaphores next and mutex?

I am not quite sure how it works, is it possible that there is 1 queue and whenever a process pauses another process is taken out of the queue and so on, and since we are dealing with semaphores we could have x.wait(), x.wait() ... x.wait() piling up without any x.signal() for a while? I am not quite sure what

if (next count > 0)
    signal(next); is supposed to do, is it to avoid x.wait() piling up? I am assuming processes call either x.wait() or x.signal(), but I don't even know why they would do that exactly.